# CORS Response Header - Gibberish

Tags: cors

I'm getting this response header from a PIWIK request. Is this a legit CORS response header?

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: â*â

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not encrypted, it's not valid, it's a bug!

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I figured.  I've searched high and low for the source of  this gibberish but have had no luck.  It's a response header from a request to Matomo. Weird.